# DBD::SQLite, how to pass array in query via placeholder?

Tags: arrays, perl, sqlite, placeholder

Let's have a table:

```
sqlite> create table foo (foo int, bar int);
sqlite> insert into foo (foo, bar) values (1,1);
sqlite> insert into foo (foo, bar) values (1,2);
sqlite> insert into foo (foo, bar) values (1,3);
```

Then SELECT some data:

```
sqlite> select * from foo where foo = 1 and bar in (1,2,3);
1|1
1|2
1|3
```

Works all right. Now I'm trying to use DBD::SQLite 1.29:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('select * from foo where foo = $1 and bar in ($2)');
$sth->execute(1,[1,2,3]);
```

And this gives me null results. DBI trace shows that 2nd placeholder is bound to array all right, but no score. If I `join` array values in a string and pass it, no result. If I flatten the array, I get predictable error of "called with N placeholders instead of 2".

I'm kinda at loss. What else is there to try?

**Upd:** All right, here's one bona fide example taken from the real world application.

First, the setup: I have several tables filled with statistical data, number of columns varies from 10 to 700+. The queries I'm talking about select subset of that data for reporting purposes. Different reports consider different aspects and therefore run different queries, one or more per request. There are more than 200 reports, i.e. 200-300 queries. This approach was developed for Postgres and now I need to scale it down and make it work with SQLite. Considering that all this works well with Postgres, I can't justify going over all queries and rewriting them. Bad for maintenance. I can and do use in-place query adjustments, like replacing = ANY () with IN (), these are minor aspects.

So, here's my example: 2 queries ran in succession for one report:

```
SELECT SPLIT, syn(SPLIT),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cagent WHERE ACD = $1 AND SPLIT = $2 AND
LOC_ID = ANY ($3) AND LOGID IS NOT NULL AND WORKMODE = 40),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cagent WHERE ACD = $1 AND SPLIT = $2 AND
LOC_ID = ANY ($3) AND LOGID IS NOT NULL AND WORKMODE = 30),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cagent WHERE ACD = $1 AND SPLIT = $2 AND
LOC_ID = ANY ($3) AND LOGID IS NOT NULL AND WORKMODE = 50),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cagent WHERE ACD = $1 AND SPLIT = $2 AND
LOC_ID = ANY ($3) AND LOGID IS NOT NULL AND WORKMODE = 220),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cagent WHERE ACD = $1 AND SPLIT = $2 AND
LOC_ID = ANY ($3) AND LOGID IS NOT NULL),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cagent WHERE ACD = $1 AND SPLIT = $2 AND
LOC_ID = ANY ($3) AND LOGID IS NOT NULL AND WORKMODE = 20),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cagent WHERE ACD = $1 AND SPLIT = $2 AND
LOC_ID = ANY ($3) AND LOGID IS NOT NULL AND WORKMODE = 80)
FROM csplit WHERE ACD = $1 AND SPLIT = $2

SELECT syn(LOGID), syn(LOC_ID), LOGID, EXTENSION, syn(ROLE), PERCENT,
syn(AUXREASON), syn(AWORKMODE), syn(DIRECTION), WORKSKILL, syn(WORKSKLEVEL),
AGTIME FROM cagent WHERE ACD = $1 AND SPLIT = $2 AND LOC_ID = ANY ($3) AND
LOGID IS NOT NULL
```

This is not the most complex example, as there can be any number of input parameters used and reused in different places in query; replacing them with generic `?` placeholders is not a trivial task. Code that runs queries against Postgres looks like that (after input cleansing et al):

```
sub run_select {
  my ($class, $dbh, $sql, @bind_values) = @_;

  my $sth;
  eval {
    $sth = $dbh->prepare_cached($sql);
    $sth->execute(@bind_values);
  };
  $@ and die "Error executing query: $@";

  my %types;
  {
    my $dbt = $dbh->type_info_all;
    @types{ map { $_->[1] } @$dbt[1..$#$dbt] } =
        map { $_->[0] } @$dbt[1..$#$dbt];
  };

  my @result;

  while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref) {
    my $i = 0;
    push @result, [ map { [ $types{${$sth->{TYPE}}[$i++]}, $_ ] } @$row ];
  };

  return \@result;
};
```

I can rewrite queries and inject values directly; SQL injection is not much of a threat because all input is untainted through regex patterns long before it can hit SQL engine. I don't want to rewrite queries dynamically for two reasons: a) it can potentially lead to problems with value quotation and b) it kinda kills the whole reason behind prepare_cached. SQL engine can't cache reuse prepared statement if it changes every time.

Now as I said, the code above works well with Postgres. Since SQLite engine itself obviously have the possibility of working with data sets, I thought it was a deficiency in DBD::SQLite implementation. So the real question sounds like: is there any way to pass a data set in a placeholder with DBD::SQLite? Not necessarily array though that would be most logical.

Comment: Perhaps you should, instead of posting made-up code, post an actual example of what data you are getting from your application/library.

Comment: -1 this question has low quality

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from foo where foo = ? and bar in (?,?,?)";
$sth->execute(1,1,2,3);
```

You can use the `x` repetition operator to generate the required number of `?`s:

```
my $sql = sprintf "select ... and bar in (%s)", join ",", ('?')x@values;
```

Comment: Can't. First, queries are passed on me from calling application (mine is a library) along with parameters and I don't want to parse it all. It can easily be much more complex than above simplified example. Second, this approach kinda spoils the whole placeholder idea in the first place -- if I have to do the parsing, I'd better inject values directly into query text to avoid headaches.

Comment: It really doesn't spoil the idea at all, since injecting the values requires properly escaping values, a problem exacerbated by passing multiple. comma separated values.  You aren't doing any parsing when you insert multiple ?s.

Comment: @Alexander: The headaches that occur when you screw up SQL quoting are very real. *DON'T DO IT YOURSELF!* (If you do, you probably end up with SQL injection vulnerabilities of the kind that totally plague PHP applications.)

Comment: @MkV: I have always thought that escaping was minor advantage of using placeholders. Their main value IMHO is in statement abstraction, caching of prepared statements and significant query speedup. Perhaps not with SQLite, although I didn't run any benchmarks to prove or disprove that.

Comment: @Donal: Never worry, paranoia to the rescue. There Ain't No Such Thing As Trusted Input, it all gets laundered thoroughly with eco-friendly, biodegradable but nevertheless reusable highly caustic regexps.

Comment: @Alex: Yet I still don't trust sanitization when I've got correct-by-construction available. For one thing, I *know* I make mistakes and I don't presume that anyone else is perfect either, yet if I know that the way it is done can only ever work perfectly or fail utterly even on simple input, I at least know that nothing's going to bite me at an unfortunate moment. (Doing a demo to your boss's boss and having things go wrong then, that's not a good feeling. Theoretically better than hitting it once rolled out in production, but practically pretty awful.)

Comment: @Donal, Not sure I get your meaning. First, I'm not familiar with what you call correct-by-construction; second, we can sit here theoretizing the whole day but I still need to get the job done. Currently I solve the problem by searching-and-exploding placeholders, but I don't like it this way - too fragile. Gotta rewrite it if something more positive comes up. As for sanitizing input, I'm doing it even within my programs called by my other programs. Just because you never know. If you're not paranoid, it doesn't mean they're not following you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [SQL::Abstract](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SQL-Abstract), like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use SQL::Abstract;

my $sqla = SQL::Abstract->new;
my %where  = (
    foo => 1,
    bar => { -in => [1,2,3] }
);

my ($sql, @params) = 
    $sqla->select('foo', '*', \%where);

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(@params);
```

Comment: It doesn't look abstract enough for my needs. See above example.  Thanks for suggestion though, I'll keep that module in mind for the future.